# Reach Router Navigate Changes URL Path But Does Not Render Component

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, reach-router

ReactJS, Reach Router, Webpack application

When trying to navigate to home after a condition check. I get a blank page albiet with the correct URL path. It doesn't enter the MyHome component at all and in the browser console I see navigated to http://localhost:[PORT] but no path

Why is it not navigating?

```
        <Router>
            <MyRoute path="/*" component={MyOne} />
            <MyRoute path="/home" component={MyHome} />
            <MyRoute path="/two" component={MyTwo} />}
        </Router>
```

MyRoute.js

```
const MyRoute= ({ component: Component}) => {


   ..........

    if (!check) {
        return navigate(`/home`)
    }

    return <Component />
}
```

**Edit**
Replacing navigate with `<Redirect to="/home" noThrow /`> works

Redirect works with componentDidCatch to prevent the tree from rendering and starts over with a new location.

React throws an error which you will see in console logs. NoThrow will prevent the error from displaying as its not a concern

However I will await a reason as to why navigate doesn't work before marking this as an answer

Comment: What's the "/*"? Have you tried moving that one below "/two"?

Comment: /* is for embedded routes.
I have tried moving it didn't work

Comment: I've also been searching for an answer to this for days. Currently using Redirect as a workaround, but don't understand why navigate isn't working.